# Which libraries in python can be used for backtesting and live trading with pandas?

Tags: python, software

Is there any libraries available in python which uses pandas and can be used for backtesting a strategy as well as develop it into a live trading system ?

Answer (score 4):

[Zipline](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zipline) is a trading library that does exactly this.